# Twillio Conversation - Facing issues while adding and removing multiple particpants

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

I am trying to add multiple participants to a particular discussion sid.
if i am trying to add single participant, it is working properly.

** this "add" method is working for adding single participant.

```
const addParticipant = async () => {

   const emitMethods = await ConversationsClient?.create(token);

   (await emitMethods.getConversationBySid(discussionSid)).add('xyz')

}
```

** but trying the same method for adding or removing multiple participants throwing error

```
const addParticipant = async () => {

   const emitMethods = await ConversationsClient?.create(token);

   (await emitMethods.getConversationBySid(discussionSid)).add('xyz','123', '!@#')

}
```

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/2.0.0/docs/classes/Conversation.html#add) you will see that you can only add one user at the same time